# Problems with syntax when attempting to update table contents (MySQL Workbench)

Tags: mysql, syntax, mysql-workbench

```
ALTER TABLE '"(File Location)"' REDEFINE "RoHS Status" CHAR(20);

UPDATE "(File Location)" SET "RoHS Status" = ' - RoHS Compliant' WHERE "RoHS Status" = 'Y'; 

UPDATE "(File Location)" SET "RoHS Status" = ' - NonRoHS Compliant' WHERE "RoHS Status" = 'N'; 

UPDATE "(File Location)" SET "RoHS Status" = '' WHERE "RoHS Status" = 'U'; 

UPDATE "(File Location)" SET "RoHS Status" = ' - RoHS Exempt' WHERE "RoHS Status" = 'E';
```

All file locations are the same, I just do not wish to disclose their location.

Comment: If you are using the workbench then it will clearly indicate which part of each line has an error< or probably the first error when there are more than 1 error per statement. So just look for the red x next to the bad statement and then look for the red underline for the proeblem area,

Comment: I have done, All the update lines (lines 2-5) are errors, however i can not find any way to fix them. My knowledge of MySQL is limited as i am still teaching myself but as far as i was aware, this code should be functional

Comment: I am getting errors stating 'syntax error, unexpected text_string'

Comment: @JamieWilletts The update lines *are* errors? Or the update lines *have* or *produce* errors? If the latter then show us those errors.

Comment: They are producing errors stated in the previous comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful with your quoting. In MysQL there are 3 types of quoting:

1. Back tick quotes ( ` )
2. Single quotes ( ' )
3. Double quotes ( " )

Back ticks are the default quoting chars. They are used to delimit a sequence of input chars to comprise an **identifier**. They are usually needed when you use input outside the allowed standard characters, which are the ASCII set and the Unicode BMP starting with value 0x80 (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifiers.html).

Single quotes denote **strings**.

Double quotes are two-fold, depending on the ANSI_QUOTES sql mode. If not set then double quotes denote **strings** too. If set however, they denote **identifiers**, just like back ticks.

Now check your code again. You are using strings where identifiers are expected, hence the syntax errors in MySQL Workbench.